# How to draw dynamic number of columns in uitableviewcell for iphone in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Can any anyone tell me how to create dynamic number of columns in uitableviewcell using custom class for uitableviewcell. i have 4 or 5 or 6 columns and it is not fixed.so how to draw the columns.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *MyIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row];

    CustomCells *cell = (CustomCells*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[CustomCells alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    else{
        [[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {

        label= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*columnWidth) , 0 ,(highestWidth + 20), tableView.rowHeight)]; 

        label.frame =CGRectMake(20+(i*columnWidth) , 0 ,(highestWidth + 20), tableView.rowHeight);
        label.text = [[searchedWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + (i*dividedWords)] texts];

        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:(20.0)];
        label.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        label.editable = NO;

        label.opaque =YES;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    }

}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@darshan is right. In iPhone, there is no concept of columns. You need to use some simple graphics methods to draw rectangles/lines. And then show your label/textview in that rect.
So, should look like table of columns & rows.

I had implemented the same, but cant give you the complete code.
Just create custom UITableViewCell (subclass it). And write following methods in it

```
 - (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position 
 {
if(columns == nil)
{
    columns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
     [columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
 }

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  // Use the same color and width as the default cell separator for now
  // CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.50);

  for (int i = 0; i < [columns count]; i++) {
    CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
  }

  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

  [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: HeyThanks.But using graphics makes it too complicated.

Comment: no.. not at all... & by the way you do not have any other option..(as per my assumptions).

Answer (score 0):

Actually in UITableView of iPhone there is no concept of columns. You can create your own custom UITableViewCell and can add subviews to it to make your desired cell. So what can you do is that you create your custom table view cell, add the desired subviews to it and then at run time you decide which views to show or hide. You can do that in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I have updated my question above.In the above code i have used uitextview as a subview .but everytime i have to alloc it,so that the tableview has become very slow.In my custom cell i havent written any code.Plz can you tell me how can i reuse my textview only once allocated?

Comment: I think your code is slow not due to allocation of textview but its due to MyIdentifier you are using. You are creating it individual for every cell. So every time framework needs to create new cell instead of reusing the cell. Because of that your tableview my populate slowly.

Comment: Even if i use  NSString *MyIdentifier =@"Cell"; I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create multiple cells - a four column cell, a three column cell etc. and choose the right one in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: But will these cells overlap,because we cannot fix the width of the cell.

Comment: you have one cell for each row of the tableview. if you want the cells to be flexible width e.g. items move/resize when device rotated then you might need to create the cells in code with subclassing rather than creating a simple cell in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create columns in UITableView.
for more detail :  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice way of dynamic table view implementation in the below link. With this you can dynamically control the items that need to be added to cell.

[iPad-Dynamic-Table-Cells](https://github.com/ecrichlow/iPad-Dynamic-Table-Cells)