# UITableView horizontal row

Tags: ios, uitableview

my table view has a custom cell that only has one button. I will like the row to be horizontal. I cannot put many buttons because I don't know how many items there will be. Or rather I have 1 rows with many columns. I want it:
a b c
not vertical.

What can I do?

Comment: It is hard to visualize what you're trying to do. Could you perhaps attach an image of what you're trying to achieve, and how the non-working version looks now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding a new button subview change the previously added buttons frames so that all the buttons had the same widths and occupy the cell.

or 
 2. Subclass `UITableViewCell`, add `NSMutableArray` to keep the buttons, override `layoutSubview` to arrange the buttons, call `setNeedsDisplay` in the method `addButton:` which will be used to add a new `UIButton` to that array, use `addButton:` at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

That's easy, but with the dynamic cell's you need to take care of cell-reusing as the reused cells will have the buttons subviews from earlier created cell - you can simply remove all the  subviews from the cell at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` before adding new buttons or you can not to use the reuse technique if there're not too many cells in the table.

Comment: From a fast googling `Surjit Joshi` and `ade` answers are looking good (I'd use `ade`'s suggestion as it allows you to reuse the cells, saves a lot allocating and redraw operations) from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939951/how-to-draw-dynamic-number-of-columns-in-uitableviewcell-for-iphone-in-objective also check the Apple documentation (it has a few samples)  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18